# Fiware: Can we use cygnus on Raspberry Pi

Tags: fiware, fiware-cygnus

Can we install cygnus on RaspberryPi? 
Thinking of using it with [Cepheus](https://fiware-cepheus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to add persistance on the gateway level.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Never tried, nevertheless it is a Java application, so having a JVM and the proper libraries should work. Most probably the memory is a problem, so it is probably you could not handle a high througput of notifications. In any case, as said, it is a matter of trying.

The keypoint for using it with Cepheus is if Cepheus notifies in the same format than Orion Context Broker. If not, Cygnus will not understand the notifications.

Another important thing is the storage aimed to be used for persistence. I don't know if any of the supported storages in Cygnus, for instance MySQL or MongoDB, can be run wihtin a Raspberry Pi! In this case, the best option may be to install the storage in a remote machine.